# chart.js how to do a xy plot around the 0/360 degree discontinuity

Tags: chart.js

I have angular data around 0 degrees:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [0.1, 359.2, 359.5, 0.2, 0.3]
```

Plotting this as a XY plot in chart.js leads to the plot jumping back and forth on a y-axis range of [0, 360]. Is there a way I can specify a y-axis range such as [355, 5] where 0 and 360 are considered the same y-axis value and thus handles the 0/360 discontinuity?